# The docker-compose project hasn't been creating on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I created a new webApi project (.Net Core) with Docker Support option enabled. However, the Visual Studio 2017 Community created only DockerFile. According some articles that I have read it should create also docker-compose project with the files: docker-compose.ci.Build and docker-compose.override? Does anybody know what I have to do to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Delete the dockerfile, right-click the project and select "Add > Docker Support" to try again.

Comment: Yeah, deleting DockerFile sometimes resolves the issue.

Comment: I tried to do that but it didn't solve my issue. It continued creating only dockerfile.